# Entity Framework get Counts of Collections and not the entire collection

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core in a Blazor WASM Application.  I have a Movie class which contains a List.  I want to show a list of Movies with the Count of Ratings and The Average of ratings but I do not need the entire list of ratings to come back for the list.

```
public class Movie
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name  {get;set;}

   public List<Rating> Ratings {get;set;}
}

public class Rating
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public decimal Value {get;set;}

 public int MovieId {get;set;}
 public Movie Movie {get;set;}
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Movie>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                return await _dataContext.Movies.Include(a => a.Rating).ToListAsync();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error in GetAllAsync()");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I Ultimately want to have the list look like

Fast and Furious  26 Ratings 4.5 avg

Taken 145 ratings 3.7 avg

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project out the aggregates like this:

```
var q = from m in db.Movies
        select new 
          { 
            m.Name, 
            Ratings = m.Ratings.Count(), 
            AverageRating = m.Ratings.Average(r => r.Value) 
          };

return await q.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed.